# Filtering data from an array which is a result from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, similarity

Okay I have a query that looks like this :

```
   "SELECT `tag_name`,`sub_tag_name` FROM phpro_tag_targets targets
    INNER JOIN  sub_tags ON targets.sub_tag_id=sub_tags.sub_tag_id
    INNER JOIN phpro_tags tags ON targets.tag_id=tags.tag_id
    WHERE tag_target_id='{$vid['tag_target_id']}'";
```

The tables themselves looks like this:

**phpro_tag_targets**:

```
   tag_target_id | tag_id  | sub_tag_id | tag_target_name | tag_type_id
     int(11)     | int(11) | int(11)    |  var_char        | int(3)
    <PK - index> |   <fk>  |  <fk>
```

**phpro_tags**:

```
  tag_id | tag_name
   <PK>  | VARCHAR
  sub_tags:
   sub_tag_id | sub_tag_name
     <PK>     | VARCHAR
```

and the result of the query looks something like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [tag_name] => Humanity [sub_tag_name] => Children ) 
    [1] => Array ( [tag_name] => Society [sub_tag_name] => Children ) 
    [2] => Array ( [tag_name] => Art and Artists [sub_tag_name] => Creativity ) 
    [3] => Array ( [tag_name] => Humanity [sub_tag_name] => Creativity ) 
    [4] => Array ( [tag_name] => Humanity [sub_tag_name] => Culture ) 
    [5] => Array ( [tag_name] => Society [sub_tag_name] => Culture ) 
    [6] => Array ( [tag_name] => unlisted [sub_tag_name] => Culture ) 
    [7] => Array ( [tag_name] => unlisted [sub_tag_name] => Culture ) 
)
```

The result is the tags and subtags associated with a piece of content (ie. video or article). I am attempting to display this information in html such that I have a `<span class="tags">` and a `<span class="subtags">`. For the above eg. data the html would look like this:

```
   <span class="tags"> Humanity Society Art and Artists unlisted </span>
   <span class=subtags> Children Creativity Culture </span>
```

Is there a way that I can somehow filter data using php (or altering the query) so that I am only displaying Each different value a single time. As I am currently using a loop to cycle through the dat and displaying the same tag, and subtags multiple times, but can't figure out how to further filter the result.

An insight into how I could do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to loop through the data array and collect all tag names and subtag names into separate arrays. Then use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicate values from an array. And finally use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join array elements to a string.

```
$tags = array();
$sub_tags = array();

// NOTE: $array is query result array
foreach ( $array as $value ) {
    $tags[] = $value['tag_name'];
    $sub_tags[] = $value['sub_tag_name'];
}

$tags = array_unique( $tags );
$sub_tags = array_unique( $sub_tags );

echo '<span class="tags">'.implode( ' ', $tags ).'</span>';
echo '<span class="subtags">'.implode( ' ', $sub_tags ).'</span>';
```

I really hope that I have correctly understood the question.

Comment: Sorry about late acceptance.  Thanks a lot! array_unique seems like it will be super handy moving forward much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can edit your query to give you a one line result with what I think you need.  The GROUP_CONCAT function with the DISTINCT option and a SEPARATOR of ' ' should give you the format you are going for.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `tag_name` SEPARATOR ' '),
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `sub_tag_name`SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM phpro_tag_targets targets
INNER JOIN sub_tags ON targets.sub_tag_id=sub_tags.sub_tag_id
INNER JOIN phpro_tags tags ON targets.tag_id=tags.tag_id
WHERE tag_target_id='{$vid['tag_target_id']}'
```

The output for this will be

```
tag_name | sub_tag_name
Humanity Society Art and Artists unlisted | Children Creativity Culture
```